# iPhone contact details corrupted how can I fix them?

Tags: ios, iphone

At some point I noticed I’m seeing vcard coding or something to that effect and a bunch of my iPhone contacts. Please look at the example is there any way to fix this without having to go into each individual contact and delete the tags etc. it looks to be some type of V card code reference.

As you can see in the attached image for Apple headquarters, there is corrupted data. This is happening in a lot of my contacts I am seeing things such as X-SOCIALPROFILE at the end of phone numbers, etc..

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a support issue, and not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the issue.
Adding my work email, I had accidentally checked sync contacts. It is Microsoft based so it corrupted a bunch of my contacts trying to pull vCard data etc.

Also, Facebook messenger was corrupting my contacts

I disabled both of these syncing features, on my Mac went into contacts and searched for “x”

I found a lot of things like X-social etc appended to phone numbers etc

Based on this search in contacts I has to manually cleanup about 30 contacts. After about 1 hour my phone was synced to the updated iCloud contacts and everything is good.

Bottom line. Choose one source of truth to sync your contacts like iCloud.

Don’t allow 3rd party apps to access your contacts.

If you need anymore information let me know

Answer (score 0):

I have another client that is experiencing the same issue (both with phone number and country name fields).  I am posting something to the Apple forum hoping that someone there has an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: As this is not an answer please move it to a comment under my original post thanks.

Comment: Regrettably, this forum will not allow me to add a comment to the original post because I don’t have a ‘rating’ of 50 or higher.

That being said, does anyone have any suggestions on how to repair this (other than manually) since my client has several hundred corrupted contacts?

I agree that there should be one ‘source of truth’ for contacts, and my client desires the contact to be in Apple - but ‘available’ in Outlook (the mail client that is needed for their business).

Thanks.